# Implementing Google Tag Manager into Android

Tags: android, android-studio, google-tag-manager

I am trying to implement Google Tag Manager by following this tutorial:  https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v4/

When I run the application, I get in the console these errors :

```
    05-22 12:27:44.490    V/GoogleTagManager﹕ Attempting to load a container from the resource ID 2131099650 (testconverteo.ismail.converteotag:raw/gtm_default_container)
    05-22 12:27:44.520    E/GoogleTagManager﹕ Invalid macro: _gtm.loadEventEnabled
    05-22 12:27:44.520    V/GoogleTagManager﹕ loadAfterDelay: containerId=GTM-XXXXX delay=29397190
    05-22 12:27:44.530    E/GoogleTagManager﹕ Invalid macro: _gtm.loadEventEnabled
    05-22 12:27:44.490    W/GoogleTagManager﹕ Failed to extract the container from the resource file. Resource is a UTF-8 encoded string but doesn't contain a JSON container
```

And I have no data in Google Analytics in real time, even more nothing which proves that my application is tracked.

If anybody has had the same problem , or he had followed the same steps and knows how to resolve this issue, please leave an explanation in comment.

The steps I've done:

- I set up the Google Play Services SDK by adding in the builde.gradle (module: app) this part of code:
  `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'`
- I add the permissions to the AndroidManifest.xml file
- I download and add a default container binary to the application
- I Create a splash screen activity where I initialize GTM by following the tutorial’s pattern
- I’ve pushed an event into a dataLayer

What I currently have in my splash screen activity is the following:

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String CONTAINER_ID = "GTM-XXXX";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashscreen);

        TagManager tagManager = TagManager.getInstance(this);
        tagManager.setVerboseLoggingEnabled(true);

        PendingResult<ContainerHolder> pending = tagManager.loadContainerPreferNonDefault(
            CONTAINER_ID,
            R.raw.gtm_default_container
        );

        pending.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<ContainerHolder>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(ContainerHolder containerHolder) {
                ContainerHolderSingleton.setContainerHolder(containerHolder);
                Container container = containerHolder.getContainer();
                if (!containerHolder.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    Log.e("IL", "failure loading container");
                    return;
                }
                ContainerHolderSingleton.setContainerHolder(containerHolder);
            ContainerLoadedCallback.registerCallbacksForContainer(container);
            containerHolder.setContainerAvailableListener(new ContainerLoadedCallback());
                startMainActivity();
            }
        }, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    private void startMainActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private static class ContainerLoadedCallback implements ContainerHolder.ContainerAvailableListener {
        @Override
        public void onContainerAvailable(ContainerHolder containerHolder, String containerVersion) {
            // We load each container when it becomes available.
            Container container = containerHolder.getContainer();
            registerCallbacksForContainer(container);
        }

        public static void registerCallbacksForContainer(Container container) {
            // Register two custom function call macros to the container.
            container.registerFunctionCallMacroCallback("increment", new CustomMacroCallback());
            container.registerFunctionCallMacroCallback("mod", new CustomMacroCallback());
            // Register a custom function call tag to the container.
            container.registerFunctionCallTagCallback("custom_tag", new CustomTagCallback());
        }

    }

}
```

And in the main Activity:

```
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    DataLayer dataLayer = TagManager.getInstance(this).getDataLayer();
    dataLayer.pushEvent("Application ouverte", DataLayer.mapOf("login page","un de plus"));
}
```

And I’ve also created this class:

```
public class ContainerHolderSingleton {

    private static ContainerHolder containerHolder;

    /**
     * Utility class; don't instantiate.
     */
    private ContainerHolderSingleton() {
    }

    public static ContainerHolder getContainerHolder() {
        return containerHolder;
    }

    public static void setContainerHolder(ContainerHolder c) {
        containerHolder = c;
    }
}
```

Please note I've hidden the Google Tag Manager container ID

Let me know if anybody wants more information

Thank you

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28765301/2835243) should be helpful.

Comment: @BishopBarber Thank you, I've read that answer before but unfortunately, I still have the same problem

Comment: I believe your problem is that you didn't add a rule that allows GTM to use your macro. `A macro is available whenever any one of its enabling rules is met`. If you are using the newest version of Tag Manager, [see here](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106961). Other else, [see here](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/2644396?hl=en&ref_topic=2574304).

Comment: You can check `GAv4` tag in your logcat for Google Analytics. Even with GTM, if you set up things correctly you will see them show up under `GAv4` in your logcat. But that's just for checking, for your problem I suspect it's on your GTM tags, rules & macros setup.

Comment: @BishopBarber , I've added some rules as you can see :
![Valid XHTML](http://nsa37.casimages.com/img/2015/06/01/150601103114993317.png).

Comment: @Mallasse Okay, and you still get the same errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace line 
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'`
with 
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'`
or
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.0.0'` (that's even better as it just includes ga and gtm related stuff)

I was lucky enough to start with 7.0.0 and saw gtm working. Then upgraded to 7.3.0 and it just stopped working. It might be fixed with new gms lib.

All that assuming you've configured your container. If not read more about that here https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6103657?hl=en&ref_topic=3441530

Comment: Thank you l lot guys, i've done what you say @fada21 and it seems that it works, I can see in the console that the hit is sent, but in google analytics i have nothing in real time

Comment: Do you have something like that as your tag definition: http://pasteboard.co/1pQOY1u3.png. Anyway I'll document my setup better in spare time and share with you. Btw recently I tested gcm 7.5.0 and it was working. That mean ```compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.5.0'``` should work from now on

Comment: Thanks a lot @fada21, I have some questions, which container do you use ? The binary or .json ? and when I change configurations of my container, should I download it and add it to my project again ?

Comment: @Mallasse It looks like the binary is recommended and most complete way: "Although using the binary file is recommended, if your container does not contain rules or tags, you may choose to use a simple JSON file instead." https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v4/

Comment: hey @Mallasse, sorry for late response. Yeah, I use binary but it's only for initial conf. Then whenever you publish conf change it gets downloaded and replaces the last one. Although when you ship new app version you may want to swap gtm conf file with to most recent one. Very small gain but you'll save some bandwith :p