# Implementing Google Analytics With Google Tag Manage: Push Event not working

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am implementing Google Tag manager following Google official Documents [Android v4 - Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v4/#init)  , but when I run the application , Only active user show in Google Analytics but Event not Pushing , review this article [Implementing Google Tag Manager into Android](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/tag-manager/_fc0v9Swq08)  also [Android Google Tag Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28762187/android-google-tag-manager) but continuously i am getting the error, while I published the container, getting in Logcat

> D/GAv4: Hit sent to the device AnalyticsService for delivery

```
private static final long TIMEOUT_FOR_CONTAINER_OPEN_MILLISECONDS = 2000;
private static final String CONTAINER_ID = "GTM-XXXX";@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashscreen);
    TagManager tagManager = TagManager.getInstance(this);
    tagManager.setVerboseLoggingEnabled(true);
    PendingResult<ContainerHolder> pending =
            tagManager.loadContainerPreferNonDefault(CONTAINER_ID,
            R.raw.gtmxxx);
    pending.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<ContainerHolder>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(ContainerHolder containerHolder) {
            ContainerHolderSingleton.setContainerHolder(containerHolder);
            Container container = containerHolder.getContainer();
            if (!containerHolder.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Log.e("container", "failure loading container");
                displayErrorToUser(R.string.load_error);
                return;
            }
            ContainerLoadedCallback.registerCallbacksForContainer(container);
            containerHolder.setContainerAvailableListener(new ContainerLoadedCallback());
            startMainActivity();
        }
    }, TIMEOUT_FOR_CONTAINER_OPEN_MILLISECONDS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

I also configured manifest file according to official document [Adding Google Tag Manager to your Project](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v4/)

Comment: you have provide some code, have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Matus sure , i provide some code